# How to ALTER TABLE [X] ADD COLUMN [Y] [type] NOT NULL in clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse, clickhouse-client

When creating a table in Clickhouse DB you can do  :

```
CREATE TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] [db.]table_name [ON CLUSTER cluster]
(
    name1 [type1] [NULL|NOT NULL] [DEFAULT|MATERIALIZED|EPHEMERAL|ALIAS expr1] [compression_codec] [TTL expr1],
    name2 [type2] [NULL|NOT NULL] [DEFAULT|MATERIALIZED|EPHEMERAL|ALIAS expr2] [compression_codec] [TTL expr2],
    ...
) ENGINE = engine
```

For adding a new column with ALTER

```
ADD COLUMN [IF NOT EXISTS] name [type] [default_expr] [codec] [AFTER name_after | FIRST]
```

It seems to not be working when for example I do

```
ALTER TABLE product_stock_history_analytics
                ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS product_id STRING NOT NULL;
```

Is there a way to set a new column to NOT NULL in a pre-existing table? Do I have to set a default value in order to achieve the desired effect ?

Answer (score 1):

ClickHouse columns are not Nullable by default.  At the moment the standard SQL NOT NULL is not supported in ALTER TABLE statements, but it's also not necessary.

```
ALTER TABLE product_stock_history_analytics ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS product_id String;
```

will create a not nullable String column using the standard (non ANSI SQL) ClickHouse syntax.